# ruby sortby 3rd element in a multidimensional array npot working properly

Tags: ruby, sorting, multidimensional-array

I'm using ruby to sort an array where each element in the array is another array.

I have this:

```
Data = Data.SortBy { |Info| info[3] }
```

example data in this column:

```
3.1
2
5.65
-1
0.4
-9.43
-10.87
-2.3
```

It should sort this into:

```
5.65
3.1
2
0.4
-1
-2.3
-9.43
-10.87
```

But it comes out like this:

```
5.65
3.1
2
0.4
-1
-10.87
-2.3
-9.43
```

It's only comparing the first char of the float... not the whole number?

Comment: Please fix your code. There should be no capitals, it's `sort_by`, not SortBy.

Comment: Thank you for your time and effort. You really helped, your answer solved my problem... oh wait... no it didn't :/ There is no need to be so pedantic and condescending.

Comment: I bet you are saying the same thing to your parser all the time...

Comment: @Mladen Jablanović Thks for your time and effert. you really help :) oh wait... no you didn't. seriously mate... /me shakes his head

Comment: If you don't supply code that allows people to reproduce the problem, it's harder for them to answer your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like it's sorting alphabetically instead of numerically, that's why "1" comes before "10".

I assume the data in info are strings. If so, you can convert them to numerical floats for the sort operation:

```
data = data.sort_by{|info| info[3].to_f}
```

Comment: This worked great, I should of been able to get this on my own. Long day :)

Comment: I have... It's not unhuman to also give a personal thks. Maybe for you though... It didn't let me do it within 5 mins as well..

Comment: Troll much LOLOLOLOLOL kthksbye

Answer (score 0):

The proper way is:

```
array.sort_by {|elt| ary = elt.split("-").map(&:to_i); ary[0] + ary[1]}
```

In simple, you can understand your code

```
array = [1,2,4,5,9]

array.sort do |a, b|
  b <=> a
end
# => [9,5,4,2,1]
```